# Write text on a div padding

Tags: html, css, z-index, padding

I currently have a div called `testLine` used for displaying a color triangle effect using css:

```
#testLine {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 47.5%;
    padding-left: 47.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#testLine:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    border-bottom: 1000px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1000px solid #4679BD;
}
```

This works fine but the issue is the following: 
How can I do to have a text over that triangle? I mean, I've tried with z-index but with no success (css it is not my strong point) and I didn't know if it is even possible to write text on it. What can be other possibilities? (I really don't want to use a resource consuming image for the background). I really appreciate any help that can lead me to a solution.

PrintScreen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPpuG.jpg

edit, html code:

```
<div id="testLine"></div>
<div id="text">Testing Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position` with alignment...something like:

```
#text {
    position: absolute;
    /* this will make div fall out of 
              page flow anad align to viewports dimension*/
    top:0;
    /* position to top*/
    left:20px;
    right:0
    /*if needed*/
    bottom:0
    /*if needed*/
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fB5C/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` with a `position` property, for example:

```
#testLine {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Without `position` property `z-index` not work